# Matrix derivatives

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

Can someone please help me with this problem? ?I've already searched for similar examples in some linear algebra textbooks, but I couldn't find any... Thanks a lot!

[image]

where $x\in \Bbb R^{n\times 1}$

Comment: What is $x{}{}$?

Comment: A matrix, or should I say a vector-valued function. In other words, f is a vector function of x.

Comment: You didn't really answer. Is it the case that $x\in \Bbb R^{n\times 1}$, for some $n\in \Bbb  N$?

Comment: What is the domain of $f$?

Comment: Oh sorry, yeah, that's the case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need for small $\|h\|$ approximations, just apply the chain rule to the function.

$$f(x) = x(x^Tx)^{-1/2}$$

Differential
$$df = dx(x^Tx)^{-1/2} - (1/2)x(2x^Tdx)(x^Tx)^{-3/2}$$

Derivative
$${\frac{df}{dx}} = I(x^Tx)(x^Tx)^{-3/2} - xx^T(x^Tx)^{-3/2}$$

Or in terms of nabla
$$\nabla_x f(x) =\frac{||x||^2I-xx^T}{||x||^3}= \frac{(x^Tx)I-xx^T}{(x^Tx)^{3/2}}$$

Comment: You got a different result. Why?

Comment: @Nathaniel It's the same. $(x^\top x)^\frac{3}{2}=(\lvert x \rvert^2)^\frac{3}{2}=\lvert x \rvert ^3$

Answer (score 4):

Let $h\in\mathbb R^n$ be a vector, then
$$f(x+h)-f(x)=\frac{x+h}{||x+h||}-\frac{x}{||x||}=\frac{||x||h-(||x+h||-||x||)x}{||x||\cdot||x+h||}$$
If $||h||$ is small, we have
$$||x+h||=\sqrt{x^Tx+2h^Tx+h^Th}=||x||\sqrt{1+2\frac{h^Tx}{x^Tx}+\frac{h^Th}{x^Tx}}=||x||+\frac{x^Th}{||x||}$$
Thus we have
$$\nabla_xf(x)=\frac{||x||I-xx^T/||x||}{||x||^2}=\frac{(x^Tx)I-xx^T}{||x||^3}$$

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you so much.