# Differentiation of a Vector with respect to a vector

Tags: derivatives, vectors, rotations, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

I am studying a paper and I am going crazy about one differentiation which it is written on it but not explained. I think I am missing something and probably something easy.

I would love if someone of you could give me an help.

My problem it is explained in the following figure:
[image]

I thank you in advance for any kind of help.

I am really stuck with it.

EDIT (Thanks to LutzL comments):

Ok to be more clear. I have the following formula.
I don't understand how is it possible that when I differentiate the formula:
\begin{equation}
\beta_{ij}=^iR\frac{\mathbf{p}_{ij}}{\delta_{ij}}
\end{equation}
I end up with the following thing:
\begin{equation}
\dot{\beta}_{ij}=
\frac{^iR}{\delta_{ij}}\left[\dot{\psi}_iS\mathbf{p}_{ij}+\left(I_{3x3}-\mathbf{\hat{p}}_{ij}\mathbf{\hat{p}}_{ij}^T\right)\dot{\mathbf{p}}_{ij}\right]
\end{equation}

I understood the first part of the equation. I think it is due to the differentiation of the rotation matrix $^iR$.

1. $\mathbf{\hat{p}}_{ij}=\left(\frac{\mathbf{p}_{ij}}{\delta_{ij}}\right)$ $\in \mathbb{R}^3$
2. $\delta_{ij}=||\mathbf{p}_{ij}||$
3. $^iR\in \mathbb{R}^{3\times3}$  is a rotation matrix $=\begin{bmatrix}
   \cos(\psi_u) & -\sin(\psi_u) & 0\\
   \sin(\psi_u)  &  \cos(\psi_u) & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 1
   \end{bmatrix}$
4. $I_{3\times3}$ is the identity matrix.
5. $S$ is a skew-symmetric matrix which is appearing into the formula for the differentiation of the rotation matrix $^iR$

I hope now it is more clear.

Comment: There is something missing. Where does the time derivative in $\dot p_{ij}$ come from?

Comment: I think it is coming from the fact that p_ij is also a function of the time.

Comment: Strip away the noise -- the rotation matrix, the unnecessary subscripts -- and you're basically asking this question (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/596835/matrix-derivatives) again.

Comment: I edited the question. Probably now it looks more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Usually 
$$
\frac{\partial F}{\partial v}(x)=F'(x)·v
$$
denotes the directional derivative of $F$ in direction $v$, while
$$
\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(x)=F'(x)
$$ 
denotes the Jacobian matrix. Your formula is mixing this somewhat.

At its core you are differentiating, omitting the indices
$$
\frac{d}{dt}_{\Big|t=0}\,\frac{p+t·\dot p}{\|p+t·\dot p\|}
=\frac{\dot p}{\|p\|}-\frac{\langle p,\dot p\rangle·p}{\|p\|^3}
$$
which then leads to your formula.

Comment: I will try to edit my question to make it more clear. Probably inserting the whole formula will make things easier.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to LutzL I was searching and I found a solution. So the second term that I was looking for is due to the derivative of vector norm.

The following is used.

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial }{\partial \mathbf{x}}\frac{x-a}{||x-a||_2}=
\frac{\mathbf{I}}{||x-a||_2}-\frac{\left(x-a\right)\left(x-a\right)^T}{||x-a||_2^3}
\end{equation}

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

$
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\BR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\d{\delta}
\def\e{{\widehat p}}
\def\p{\partial}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\dgrad#1#2{\frac{d #1}{d #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
$Drop the distracting $(i,j)$ subscripts and define the variables
$$\eqalign{
\d &\doteq \|p\|,\qquad
\e &\doteq \frac{p}{\d}
\qquad\qquad\quad\qquad
\\
}$$
First differentiate $\d$ using the product rule
$$\eqalign{
\d^2 &= p^Tp \\
2\d\,d\d &= 2p^Tdp \\
\grad{\d}{p} &= \fracLR{2p}{2\d} \;=\; \e
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad
\\
}$$
then differentiate $\e$ using the quotient rule
$$\eqalign{
\e &= \frac{p}{\d} \\
d\e &= \fracLR{\d\,dp-p\,d\d}{\d^2} 
 &= \fracLR{I-\e\e^T}{\d}dp \\
\grad{\e}{p} &= \fracLR{I-\e\e^T}{\d} \\
}$$
Applying this last result to the derivative in your question
$$\eqalign{
\grad{(R\e)}{p}
 &= R\gradLR{\e}{p} 
 &= \fracLR{R}{\d}\BR{I-\e\e^T} \
\quad\quad\;
\\
}$$
yields the desired result.